# Socket buffers getting overridden when two parallel sockets are communicating

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I'm working on a project where I need to read data from one sensor1 via TCP protocol using socket programming continuously, do some calculations on the data, and then send some control commands to sensor2 via UDP protocol. This both tasks has to be performed simultaneously inside an infinite loop.

Below is the snippet of code where I have abstracted away the details for ease of understanding.

```
a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
a_addr = (a_IP, a_PORT)
a_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, local_interface.encode())

def run_loop():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as b_socket:
        b_socket.setblocking(False)
        b_socket_status = b_socket.connect_ex((b_IP, b_PORT))
        if b_socket_status != 0:
            raise Exception("Cannot connect to b")
           
        
        while True:
            data = b_socket.recv(SIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            if data.startswith(b'####'):
                if (some_condition):
                    message = get_msg()
                    int sendto_recv = a_socket.sendto(message, a_addr)
                    print(f"response: {sendto_recv}")

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    run_loop()
```

In the above piece of code when this line of code executes - `"data = b_socket.recv(SIZE)"` we read data from sensor1 and this line of code `"a_socket.sendto(message, a_addr)"` defined inside fun() method sends commands to sensor2. It doesn't send the message to sensor2.
My code works as a client which connects to one socket to recv and sends a command to another socket.

Does this code suffer from a synchronization problem?
Is there a way to allocate different internal data buffers to different sockets?
Do I need to implement the code using threads?

Comment: "doesn't send the message as expected" is not a problem description.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your reply, I wanted to mean as the sento() method is expected to send the message to the respective address, is not accomplished, which in simple words mean that sendto() is somewhere internally due to some issue is unable to send the commands to sensor2. I hope it clarified your doubt and also added few lines to clarify the problem statement.

Comment: 'is not accomplished' and 'is unable to send' are not problem descriptions either. What happens instead? Nothing? Error? Exception? Crash? Computer explodes?

Comment: "Nothing happens", no exception or crash. If my sensor2 receives data, then I would know that. But since nothing happens, so it seems the method sendto() is not working/sending the message due to some reason. While if I remove this line of code - "data = b_socket.recv(SIZE)" then it works.

Comment: Are you sure it gets to sendto? I expect it immediately breaks out of the loop because the socket is nonblocking and there is nothing to receive yet

Comment: Yes, it goes, but only if there is less delay. The server "b" expects UDP datagrams from the client more frequently than I initially coded.

Answer (score 0):

The code started working once implemented with multi-threading. Since a single client was connecting to two servers, one for receiving and another for sending, they had to be synchronised. So once synchronization was implemented using two threads, similar to the classical "Producer-Consumer" problem. The two threads, along with the main thread of execution, were able to perform the desired communication at the correct frequencies.

The frequency here means the rate at which the server expects continuous data.  It was implemented using `time.sleep()` which was different for two threads, and a shared stack() from where the producer data was consumed.
Here is simple version of the code:

```
def tcp_client(lock, udp_stack):
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        data = a_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        udp_stack.append(data)
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.05)

def udp_client(lock, udp_stack):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if udp_stack:
            lock.acquire()
            data = udp_stack.pop()
            lock.release()
            message = prepare_message(data)
            b_socket.sendto(message, b_addr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()
    udp_stack = deque()

    tcp_thread = threading.Thread(target=tcp_client, args=(lock, udp_stack))
    udp_thread = threading.Thread(target=udp_client, args=(lock, udp_stack))

    tcp_thread.start()
    udp_thread.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        tcp_thread.join()
        udp_thread.join()
```